# Decrypt Data which was encrypted with MS DPAPI with JNA

Tags: java, windows, encryption, jna, dpapi

is it possible to decrypt data which was encrypted with MS DPAPI? For example i want to decrypt a digital certificate from the windows registry.

```
byte[] byteArray = (byte[]) Advapi32Util.registryGetValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\SystemCertificates\\AuthRoot\\Certificates\\02FAF3E291435468607857694DF5E45B68851868", "Blob");

byte[] decrypted = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(byteArray);

String stringDecrypted = new String(decrypted);
System.out.println(stringDecrypted);
```

But i get an Win32 Exception: Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: Data are invalid.

I don't found any information about this Exception. So what das this mean?? And could i decrypt these files like i want it or is it not possible?

Thnaks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882(v=vs.85).aspx), you're missing six additional arguments to `cryptUnprotectData`.

Even if these arguments are marked "optional", you still need to declare them in your interface method signature.

**UPDATE**

Based on the MSDN documentation:

```
BOOL WINAPI CryptUnprotectData(
  _In_        DATA_BLOB *pDataIn,
  _Out_opt_   LPWSTR *ppszDataDescr,
  _In_opt_    DATA_BLOB *pOptionalEntropy,
  _Reserved_  PVOID pvReserved,
  _In_opt_    CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT *pPromptStruct,
  _In_        DWORD dwFlags,
  _Out_       DATA_BLOB *pDataOut
);
```

The second, third, fourth, and fifth arguments can probably be `null`.  The sixth argument can *probably* be zero.  The final argument needs to be an appropriately allocated [`DATA_BLOB`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinCrypt.DATA_BLOB.html) where the function can store its results (this structure is defined in JNA's `platform.jar`).  Don't forget to free the `DATA_BLOB`'s `pbData` field when you're done with it, passing its value to `LocalFree`.

Comment: and what are the exact arguments i need to add. i think the arguments must be the ones that uses DPAPI to encrypt the data. but i found no information what exact parameters they use. so it's a little bit hard to find out the arguments i need

Comment: the probelem is that the JNA function cryptUnprotectData() only accept these arguments:

byte[] data OR 
byte[] data, byte[] entropy, int flags, WinCrypt.CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT prompt OR
byte[] data, int flags

see here (https://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32Util.html)

so i don't know which values i have to set there :(

Comment: According to [the latest on github, `cryptUnprotectData()`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32.java#L72-L112) matches the docs on MSDN.  `jna.java.net` has not been used in years.

Comment: Are you able to unprotect the data using just native code?

Comment: i see one difference between my usage and yours: i used Crypt32Util you refer to Crypt32 only. But Crypt32 is only an interface. so i have to implement it by myself or i'm wrong? i'm not the best programmer :( What do you mena exactly with: i'm able to unprotect the data just native code?

Comment: No, you don't have to implement yourself.  Crypt32Util uses Crypt32; the interface provides a structure that JNA then maps onto a native library with `Native.loadLibrary()`.  The author of Crypt32Util just provided a few shortcuts against the native library definition.

Comment: okay, but in CryptUtil32 i don't have all the parameters which are given in Crypt32