# Missing artifact net.sourceforge.jdpapi:jdpapi-java:jar:1.0.1

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, pom.xml, sourceforge

I'm using the below xsd in my POM.XML, I'm getting the ERROR : Missing artifact net.sourceforge.jdpapi:jdpapi-java:jar:1.0.1

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: the issue can not be in these lines. can you provide your full pom file?

Answer (score 1):

Your requested dependency jdpapi is not available in [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjdpapi).

You could download the jar from the [project home page at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=209799) and upload the jar into yout local Maven repository by using the install plugin (please check the first example [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)). This would make your project compile, but you still would have to add the jdpapi-dll (included in the download mentioned before) to your path in order to run the project.

However, jdpapi could be an abandoned project, as the last update of the project homepage dates back to 2007. You might want to check the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278054/decrypt-data-which-was-encrypted-with-ms-dpapi-with-jna) suits your needs.